# Detect if the animation is using to many recources on the client machine

Tags: angular, google-chrome, css-animations

I am showing an animation on my login page, but on some older machines this animation is slowing down the machine, so it is very difficult to make a login.

My question is, is it possible to detect if the machine is low on resources?. If it is low on resources, then I will show a static image instead of the animation.